# Magento why Catalog Model returns same url for several different categories on a loop?

Tags: php, magento

I want to display the category links on a product page.

So I do this:

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$categories_ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();
?>

<?php if (count($categories_ids > 0)): ?>
  <ul class="categorias-principais">
    <?php foreach ($categories_ids as $cat_id): ?>
      <?php $category = $category_model->load($cat_id) ?>
      <?php if(!$category->getIsActive()) continue; ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>">
          <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
        </a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

I get the correct names, but the url is always equal the first one, for the rest of the categories, why? getName, getUrlPath, all returns correct values, but not getUrl()

I also tried using a helper:

```
<a href="<?php echo $category_helper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>">
    <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
</a>
```

but the problem persists

this is the generated html

```
<ul class="categorias-principais">
  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/index.php/maquiagem.html">
      Maquiagem
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/index.php/maquiagem.html">
      Corpo e Banho
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/index.php/maquiagem.html">
      Sub segundo
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/index.php/maquiagem.html">
      Unhas
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

When I change my collection using:

```
$categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection();
```

instead of getting the categories ids and loading the category with the model, I can use getUrl() with success, but then getName() and getIsActive() won't work anymore, so I mixed the two instances types, it is very lame, but if nobody can give me a better answer, I will post this as one.

new code working:

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection();
?>

<?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
  <ul class="categorias-principais">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $_category): ?>
      <?php $_category_element = $category_model->load($_category->getId()) ?>
      <?php if(!$_category_element->getIsActive() || $_category->getLevel() != 2) continue; ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>">
          <?php echo $_category_element->getName() ?>
        </a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code, check with parameter as category like $_cat->getUrl($_cat); you did not include parameter in your first code.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
$_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
 echo $_cat->getUrl($_cat);
echo $_cat->getName();
}
```